# Getting a dual of a boolean expression

Tags: boolean-logic, discrete-mathematics, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I am brushing up on my boolean algebra and I am confused which one is actually the correct method?

[What's the difference between the dual and the complement of a boolean expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11783407/whats-the-difference-between-the-dual-and-the-complement-of-a-boolean-expressio)

[duality principle in boolean algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408409/duality-principle-in-boolean-algebra)

```
F(X,Y) = X + Y

DUAL: XY
```

or is it `DUAL: X'Y'` ?

Answer (score 1):

In one word it is : `X'Y'` . simply [duality principle](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Duality_Principle_%28Boolean_Algebras%29) is :

> Let (S,∨,∧) be a Boolean algebra.
>   Then any theorem in (S,∨,∧) remains valid if both ∨ and ∧ are interchanged, and also ⊥ and ⊤ are interchanged throughout the whole theorem.

So you have to interchange `+` with `.` and `True` with `False`. So whether `X` and `Y` are true of false they must be replace with `X'` and `Y'`.

If you want to understand better to read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_principle_%28Boolean_algebra%29#Duality_principle). And also you can see some good examples in [this](http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/showthread.php?t=49437) forum.